# Can Azure WebJobs work with the non-classic storage accounts

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

All of the WebJobs samples I've come across they always show a classic storage account used. Can WebJobs be used with new ARM based storage accounts? If so, the connection strings are a lot longer with new accounts. Do you still copy the entire connection string and place it in the app.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Azure web jobs can work with Resource Manager based storage accounts. The connection string is similar to what it used to be for classic storage account.

The major difference between classic and RM storage used to be that application diagnostics could be written to a storage table in classic storage account but not RM storage table.